# Can anyone tell me why my program is going in infinite Loop?

Tags: c++, loops

Why my code is giving an Infinite loop and i have checked my code many times and I don't know where the mistake is but my output is 34 in an infinite loop and it is a code for doubly linked list!

So please tell me where the mistake is as well as why my loop is showing 34 instead of 77 in my code and is there any problem in my print function?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};

class Linked
{
public:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    Linked()
    {
        head=NULL;
        tail=NULL;
    }

    void add(int data,int position)
    {
        Node *n=new Node;
        Node *n1=new Node;
        n->data=data;
        n->next=NULL;
        n->prev=NULL;
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            head=n;
            tail=n;
            cout<<"Linked list formed"<<endl;
        }
        if(position==0)
        {
            head->prev=n;
            n->next=head;   
            head=n;
            cout<<"Linked list created"<<endl;

        }
        else
        {

            n1=head;
            int posi=position;
            while(posi>1)
            {
                n1=n1->next;
                posi--;
            }
            n->next=n1->next;
            n->next->prev=n;
            n1->next=n;
            n->prev=n1;
        }
    }


    void print()
    {
        Node *n=new Node;
        n=head;
        while(n!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<n->data<<endl;
            n=n->next;
        }
    }

};
int main()
{
    Linked l;

    l.add(34,0);
    l.add(77,0);
    // l.add(44,1);
    // l.add(90,2);
    l.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect time to learn to use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You have two loops. Which goes into "infinite" looping?

Comment: Change your second `if` to an `else if`, and it works. I can't say why, however.

Comment: What happens if I have only 2 nodes, but advance to position 5?  Definitely time to use a debugger.

Comment: You have a memory leak.  You allocate memory for `n1`, then make the `n1` pointer point to the `head` node, thus overwriting the location of the allocated memory.

Comment: The `n1` is a pointer and doesn't need to be initialized to a newly allocated chunk of memory.  You should move the declaration of `n1` into the `else` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add (data,position) has 2 problems.

For the very first node in Doubly Linked List , once head and tail are pointed to the same node, we are done. Position do not matter, when there is no node.

So stop add logic after "Linked List Formed". Add Else and move rest all code inside, It works as expected.

Code should be able to assert Head-> Prev and Tail-> next to be null.

Also while adding a single new node, you do not want to allocate memory for 2x Nodes.

Do not call new Node () for n1.